# Sprockets Error : Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, tilt

I am facing the weird error of sprockets with tilt gem.
Basically I am loading images on ERB template (generated with Tilt) with the image tag but when the template is rendered it shows `Sprockets::Rails::Helper:: AssetNotFound`.
`The asset "button.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.`.
I have configured my assets path properly below I will be attaching the file.
And another thing is when I hit the back button and refresh the page the image gets loaded with the proper assets.
I have tried with changing assets paths as well as tried `rake assets:precompile` but still it remains the same.
All the assets are located at:
`app/assets/images`

merge.rb

```
class Generator

            include ApplicationHelper
            include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
            include Sprockets::Rails::Helper
            def initialize(template, scope = {})
              scope.each do |k, v|
                instance_variable_set k, v
              end

              f = "#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{template}.html.erb" if File.exist? "#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{template}.html.erb"


              if f
                @template = Tilt::ERBTemplate.new(f)
              else
                f = "#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{template}" if File.exist? "#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{template}"

                @template = Tilt.new(f)
              end
            end

            def request
              ActionDispatch::Request.new({})
            end

            def render
              @template.render(self) ===> Here is the render error
            end
         end
```

template.erb

```
     <div class="facility-button">
       <center><%= link_to image_tag("button.jpg" , style: "max-width: 100%;height: auto;") , "#{@email.url}" %></center>
     </div>
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'


Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[vendor.js]
```

development.rb

```
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
```

Please write down the comments if anything is unclear.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By adding this my problem is solved.

`<center><%= link_to image_tag(ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("button.jpg") , style: "max-width: 100%;height: auto;") , "#{@email.url}" %></center>`

Thanks if anyone can detail why this works!